# Error while running curl command curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am trying to run the following curl command but getting response as follows

**curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application**

### RESPONSE:

curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --show-error --fail --silent --request POST --url http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/deployment/create --header 'Authorization: Basic ZGVtbzpkZW1v' --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data;' --form deployment-name=rest-deployment --form my-project-test.bpmn=@/definitions/my-project-test.bpmn

### curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application

000

[image]

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Does `/definitions/my-project-test.bpmn` exist? Is it readable?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes the file exists and has permission to read. I added screenshot. Please check.

Comment: That's not the same path. The `/` at the beginning of `/definitions...` makes it an absolute path, meaning it starts at the root of the system volume, not down in `~/OneDrive/...`. Try removing the `/`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Getting same error with complete path as well. Please advise.

curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --show-error --fail --silent --request POST --url http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/deployment/create --header 'Authorization: Basic ZGVtbzpkZW1v' --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data;' --form deployment-name=rest-deployment --form my-project-test.bpmn=@C:/Users/gupta/OneDrive/Desktop/Camunda/BPMNs/definitions/my-project-test.bpmn
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application

Comment: That looks like a mix of Windows and Unix path syntax. Are you using WSL or something like that? If so, I have no idea if that syntax will work. Does `ls -l 'C:/Users/gupta/OneDrive/Desktop/Camunda/BPMNs/definitions/my-project-test.bpmn'` successfully show the file?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I am using git bash .

The below command doesn't work


$ ls -l 'C:/Users/gupta/OneDrive/Desktop/Camunda/BPMNs/definitions/my-project-test.bpmn'
ls: cannot access 'C:/Users/gupta/OneDrive/Desktop/Camunda/BPMNs/definitions/my-project-test.bpmn': No such file or directory

Comment: So that's not a correct path. Try `echo ~/OneDrive/Desktop/Camunda/Deployment_Shell_Script/definitions` and see what it prints.

Comment: @GordonDavisson

It prints the complete path

$ echo ~/OneDrive/Desktop/Camunda/Deployment_Shell_Script/definitions
/c/Users/gupta/OneDrive/Desktop/Camunda/Deployment_Shell_Script/definitions

Comment: @GordonDavisson it was a mistake in my path. I am able to run the script after correcting it. Thanks for your guidance hints.